# Find search string in url

Tags: next.js, next.js13

How do I get the id within my url. If I try the following, the id is always null

app/api/predictions/[id]/route.ts

```js
export async function GET(request: Request) {

  const {
    searchParams
  } = new URL(request.url);
  const id = searchParams.get('id');
  console.log("PARAMS: " + id)

  const response = await fetch(`https://api..../${id}`, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Token ${process.env.REPLICATE_API_TOKEN}`,
    },
  });
  ....
}
}
```

Comment: It should work with your code with destructuring. I think there is no search params in your url.

Comment: According to the Next.Js documentation: ` const { id } = request.query`.  https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/api-routes#dynamic-api-routes